# A cinema has three screens. $600$ people visit the cinema. $35$% go to screen 1. Four times as many go to screen 2 as go to screen 3

Tags: percentages

A cinema has three screens.
$600$ people visit the cinema.
$35$% go to screen 1.
Four times as many go to screen 2 as go to screen 3.

How many go to screen 2?

This is what I have done:

$35$% of $600$ is $210$.

$600-210=390$

$4x+x=390$

$x=78$

$312$ people went to screen 2.

Is it right?

My question here, though, is whether the answer would stay the same if I say "four times more people went to screen 2 than to screen 3".

Comment: You are right.  And changing the wording would change the equation. Four times as many is $4x$.  Four times more is generally $x+4x$ which would be $5x$.  Although I see this wording get messed up in news reports etc. all the time.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. 

But: I used the formula 4x+x for wording Four Times As Many - which you said is 4x? 
I am confused ;/

Comment: Oh.  sorry.  I was unclear.  I meant $4x+x$ just for screen 2.  So your equation would be $(x+4x)+x=390$  Which becomes $6x=390$.  If it said Four Times More.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7894/x-times-as-many-as-or-x-times-more-than#7897

Answer (score 0):

Well, 35% of 600 is 210.  That means there are 390 people left over.  If we try out the "multiples of 4" thing, we get$$1, 4$$$$2, 8$$$$3, 12$$$$4, 16$$$$...$$$$78, 312$$If we kept going to the point I stopped, we would get 312+78=390, so 312 people went to screen 2 and 78 people went to screen 3.